# Update and delete in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I was undergoing through "Programming Hive" and found the below.

```
Hive offers no support for rowlevel
inserts, updates, and deletes. Hive doesn’t support transactions.
```

But on CDH5 I am able to add a row in to my table.  But update and delete are throwing errors as "Semantic Error". I read that ACID properties can be set on hive but its not working.

> Question : Can we update and delete a record in hive?

Comment: Seems that reference is outdated. "*INSERT...VALUES, UPDATE, and DELETE have been added to the SQL grammar, starting in Hive 0.14*" -- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions

Comment: Released 2012? Oh, yeah, really outdated.

Comment: Thanks... i got my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Hive is not for OLTP but now it does support ACID operations and you have to change some configurations for it. For trying, do the following:

```
    set hive.support.concurrency = true;
    set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
    set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
    set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
```

#### ACID transactions (Insert, Update & Delete)

- Step-1 `create table testTableNew(id int ,name string ) 
         clustered by (id) into 2 buckets
         stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');`
- Step-2 `insert into table testTableNew    values (1,'row1'),(2,'row2'),(3,'row3');`
- Step-3 `update testTableNew   set name = 'updateRow2' where id = 2;`
- Step-4  `delete from  testTableNew where id = 1;`